# Best way to solve probability problem

Tags: probability

You’re designing a new ultra low power digital wireless communication
device. During testing of your prototype, you observe that 55% of bits sent are 1’s and 45%
of bits sent are 0’s. If a 1 is sent, the probability of an error is 0.17. If a 0 is sent, the probability of
an error is 0.09. Assume the transmission of each bit is an independent event and that the errors
are also independent given the true values of the bits that were sent.

From this I get:

$P(1) = P(\text{"bits are 1"}) = .55$

$P(0) = P(\text{"bits are 0"}) = .45$

$P(E|1) = P(\text{"get an error given 1 bit is sent"})  = 0.17$

$P(E| 0) = P(\text{"get an error given 0 bit is sent"})  = 0.09$

What is the probability that the string 1011 is received correctly?

My thought process is that I need to what $P(E^c)$, which is the probability of sending it correctly.

**If that is correct**, I get:

$P(E^c)$ = $P(E|1)P(1)$ + $P(E|0)P(0)$ = .134

From here I can find the $$P(1011|E^c)$$

which would be my answer.

so my question is whether or not this is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: If the original string is $1101$ then the probability all of its bits are sent without error is $0.83 \times 0.83 \times 0.91 \times 0.83$

Comment: How come I don't have to find the P( "string is sent correctly")? I thought it'd have to be the $ P( "it's correct")^3$ *$ P(1) $ + $ P( "it's correct")$*$P(0)$

Answer (score 2):

That should work. I would be more concrete, personally, because we've been given some information we don't actually need (assuming what I think is the most reasonable interpretation, namely "Given that 1011 is sent, what is the probability we receive 1011?").

We receive 1011 correctly if and only if three times we send 1 and receive 1, and one time we send 0 and receive 0. (Those things have to happen in a certain order, but that will come out in the wash.)

If we send 1, we get an error with 0.17 probability, so we receive 1 with 0.83 probability.

If we send 0, we get an error with 0.09 probability, so we receive 0 with 0.91 probability.

Therefore the answer is $$0.83 \times 0.91 \times 0.83 \times 0.83$$
corresponding to $1011$.

The reason we don't need the "55%" information is that we've been given precisely the test string already, so we don't need to quantify over which string is being sent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Patrick's answer to the question if 1011 is sent, but I think it could be looked at as what if 1011 is received.  In that case the 55% and 45% do matter.

The probability that a 1 is sent, if a 1 is received can be calculated as:

$P(1 tx|1 rx) = \frac{P(1 rx|1 tx)P(1 tx)}{P(1 rx)}=\frac{P(1 rx|1 tx)P(1 tx)}{P(1 rx|1 tx)P(1 tx)+P(1 rx|0 tx)P(0 tx)}=\frac{0.83*0.55}{0.83*0.55+0.09*0.45}\approx0.9185$

similarly

$P(0 tx|0 rx) = \frac{P(0 rx|0 tx)P(0 tx)}{P(0 rx)}=\frac{P(0 rx|0 tx)P(0 tx)}{P(0 rx|0 tx)P(0 tx)+P(0 rx|1 tx)P(1 tx)}=\frac{0.91*0.45}{0.91*0.45+0.17*0.55}\approx0.8141$

$P(1101 rx|1101 tx)=P(1 tx|1 rx)^3*P(0 tx|1 rx)\approx0.9185^3*0.8141\approx0.6309$